# CSS: Fade out only if visible

Tags: css, sass, css-animations

I wonder if it is possible to solve this with only CSS or SASS.
I have a website that has a popup that fades in if the browser window is smaller in width than $min-width pixels and fades out otherwise and stays hidden.

```
@media screen and (min-width: $min-width) {
    .app-screen {
        -webkit-animation: fade_out 0.5s forwards;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: $min-width - 1) {
    .app-screen {
        -webkit-animation: fade_in 0.5s forwards;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to post my animations:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fade_in {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade_out {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when users with a big window enter the site the popup appears and fades out. The popup is hidden by default in the css but since the fade out criteria is met, the fade_out animation is started. But I don't want it to start if the popup is already hidden.

Is there some SASS solution like "@if opacity > 0" I can before my fade-out animation or an animation property I've missed?

Comment: What does your animation do, which properties are modified?

Comment: @CBroe Sorry, updated the question

Comment: I don't understand the goal here.  When should the popup appear and disappear, for both small and large browsers?

Comment: @andi When the browser window is smaller than $min-width then the popup fades in, when it is bigger it fades out

Comment: _“The popup is hidden by default in the css”_ - and how is it hidden? If you just hide it using `display:none`, then the animation can change opacity all day long if it feels like it, it won’t have any visible effect anyway.

Comment: You expect this transition to happen on window resize?  If not, I need clarification - please fill in the blanks:  "on small browsers, this popup will appear when ____ and disappear when ____.  on large browsers, this popup will appear when ____ and disappear when ____."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this with CSS3 transitions instead of animations.

```css
/* Assuming $min-width: 700px; */

.app-screen {
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    .app-screen {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 699px) {
    .app-screen {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="app-screen">
  <p>You can only see me on small screens.</p>
</div>
```

Note that the way I have it requires you to use the same easing function to fading in as fading out (some people prefer to have ease-in one way and ease-out the other way).

Comment: Thank you! Worked exactly like I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

i propose a very simplistic approach.

```
.app-screen {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
@media screen and (max-width: $min-width) {
    table {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

This way if the screen is initially loaded bigger than @min-width nothing will happen, if smaller the screen will fade in. When the screen is dragged bigger or smaller, the screen will accordingly fade in or out.

Cheers